# Increasing/decreasing Cross-sell products limit?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cross-sells, magento-2.1.7

I'm trying to increase the cross-sell products on the cart page up to 5.

In **Magento-1**, this is possible by overriding a checkout block (or changing a var in the core). I've been trying to use something similar to do this in **Magento-2** but I am unable to produce any results.

Could someone please help me with increasing the limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily change following variable in **Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php**

```
protected $_maxItemCount = 4;
```

[Check more detail here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php#L22)

**NB: Don't modify core file.**

[Update]

Make sure your module depends on '**Magento_Checkout**' module in module.xml

> create Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

> Create **Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" />
</config>
```

> Create **Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Block\Cart;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock as StockHelper;

class Crosssell extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory $productLinkFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\RelatedProducts $itemRelationsList,
        StockHelper $stockHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutSession,
            $productVisibility,
            $productLinkFactory,
            $itemRelationsList,
            $stockHelper,
            $data
        );
        // this variable you can change what you need
        $this->_maxItemCount = 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never edit core files.

Comment: Yes, But he is looking for class for overwrite.

Comment: @SohelRana by default 4 product will display in magento2?

Comment: Yes @NagarajuK by default 4 product will display. check this file Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell  variable $_maxItemCount.

Answer (score 0):

> For magento 2 **Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Rule-Based Product Relations > Maximum Number of Products in Cross-Sell Product List**

Comment: This seems to be in adobe commerce only, not the community version